# using jsonp with ashx handler

Tags: jquery, jsonp, ashx

Can anyone give me a clear walkthrough of how to call an ashx handler with jsonp or tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I have a javascript function on one subdomain trying to call an ashx handler on another subdomain.  When I try I get back a status of 200 but it still gets into my error handling and reports a thrownError of SyntaxError: Invalid character.  I've found a couple of threads on jquery and jsonp, but only one which actually showed any code related to ashx.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be working and I'm not sure why.  Here's the code from the javascript call and then the ashx response.

```
var sPay = getEl('chkPay').checked ? "pay=1" : "";
var sUrl = "/Calculator/GetCalcResult.ashx?jsoncallback=?" + sPay;

$.getJSON(sUrl, function (data) {
    console.log("Success:" + data);
}).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log("Status:" + xhr.status);
    console.log("Error:" + thrownError);
});
```

And then the ashx handler...

```
var jsonstr = 
                 "{\"calculatorresults\":{" +
                    "\"employees\" : \"" + employeeCount + "\"" +
                    "\"pay\" : \"" + calculationResult.PayTotal + "\"" +
                    "\"total\" : \"" + calculationResult.Total + "\"" +
                "}}";

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1});", context.Request["jsoncallback"], jsonstr));
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently struggled with this as well.... here's a very simplified version of my solution that includes the basic necessary code.

I ran into cross domain issues when trying to pass json to an ashx page and retrieve json data from that ashx page.  In this example, I am sending a SessionKey to the ashx page and it returns the ID of an object.

JQuery AJAX call from the client page:

```
function CallASHXPage()
{
    var strJson = '{ "Request": { "SessionKey": "ABCD-1234" } }';

    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:55724/RemoteJsonpTest.ashx?data=" + strJson,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        // handle the output here
        alert(data.Response.OutputID);
    });
}
```

Here is the code on the ASHX page:

```
// read in data param
string JSON = context.Request.QueryString["data"];

// execute your ASHX code here

// prepare resposne data
string strResponse = "{\n";
strResponse += "\t\"Response\":\n";
strResponse += "\t{\n";
strResponse += "\t\t\"OutputID\": "12345"\n";
strResponse += "\t}\n";
strResponse += "}\n";

// output response wrapped in callback function
string output = context.Request.Params["callback"];
output += "(" + strResponse + ");";
context.Response.Write(output);
```

Comment: missing content-type